# how tp prevent duplication in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

As shown in the below posted code, the array arr wil contain obj.name and obj.text every time the function func is called.
what at i want to know is, is there a recommended way in javascript to prevent the array from having the same obj.name and obj.text more than once?

**note**: the function func contains the object obj but actually it has more than two properties

please let me know the recommended way in javascript to prevent duplicate entries to the array
**code**

```
  func(obj) {

  obj.name = name;
  obj.text = text;

  arr.push(obj);
  }
```

Comment: duplicate against what? just name, name and text jointly?

Comment: Where are `name` and `text` coming from? Do you want to really modify `obj`?

Comment: Use a `Map` object instead of an array with the item you want to avoid a duplicate of as the key.  When you're all done adding items, you can fetch an array from the Map object if you want or need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the object of the array that matches with the `name` and `text` of already existing object. You can use,

`arr.find(item => item.name === obj.name && item.text === obj.text)`

It will return a object if object with `name` and `text` value already exist in the `arr` array else `undefined`.

```
 func(obj) {

  obj.name = name;
  obj.text = text;
  var existingItem = arr.find(item => item.name === obj.name && item.text === obj.text);
    if(!existingItem){
      arr.push(obj);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

May be in new answers you will get the best suggesstion, but what you can do is

```
  func(obj) {

     obj.name = name;
     obj.text = text;

     var index = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === obj.name);
     if (index !== -1) {
       arr.splice(index, 1);
     }
     arr.push(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

To avoid duplicate on name, use arr as an object (and yeah better change its name too ;) ) and use the name as a key :

```
func(obj) {
  obj.name = name;
  obj.text = text;
  arr[name] = obj;
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicates on name and text you could use the same idea :

```
func(obj) {
  obj.name = name;
  obj.text = text;
  arr[name] = arr[name] || {};
  arr[name][text] = obj;
}
```

Edit: in this case arr would be an object and not an array. You would be able to iterate through its properties with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Only integers can be used as an array key to access elements. If you use a string, the array will get a property with that value, but that property will not be included in the array's elements.

Comment: True that, it'll be an object with properties but still works for avoiding duplicates.

Comment: Why use an array at all when you use it like an object? This is totally confusing!

Comment: Your last line generates an error, as `arr[name]` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, changed the code so that it should work. Also precised that we would work with an object and not an array. I believe the point here was to remove duplicates and an object for this looks better to me.